# Fail pushing a repository after a merge

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had a branch that I wanted to merge with the master. I used the following commands:

```
git checkout master
git merge lwIP
```

And I obtained the following answer, that I think it's correct:

```
fer@fer-Inspiron-5558:~/workspaceSDK/ControlMetro$ git merge lwIP
Updating 2f1a663..0ce296e
Fast-forward
 .../sensores/sensores_botones.c                    |   6 +-
 src/app/control_metro/main.c                       |  15 +-
 .../{funciones_com_VGA.c => funciones_com_lwIP.c}  |  94 +++++-
 .../funciones_comunicacion.h                       |   1 +
 .../tarea_comunicacion.c                           |   8 +-
 src/hw_services/display_vga/display_vga.c          |   2 +-
 src/hw_services/hal_core/gpio_services.c           | 171 +++++++++++
 src/hw_services/hal_core/gpio_services.h           |  29 ++
 src/hw_services/hal_core/hw_abstraction.c          | 314 ---------------------
 src/hw_services/hal_core/hw_abstraction.h          |  52 ----
 src/hw_services/hal_core/timer_services.c          | 281 ++++++++++++++++++
 src/hw_services/hal_core/timer_services.h          |  74 +++++
 src/hw_services/lwIP/lwIP_server.c                 | 164 +++++++++++
 src/hw_services/lwIP/lwIP_server.h                 |  17 ++
 14 files changed, 844 insertions(+), 384 deletions(-)
 rename src/app/control_metro/tarea2_comunicacion_exterior/{funciones_com_VGA.c => funciones_com_lwIP.c} (56%)
 create mode 100644 src/hw_services/hal_core/gpio_services.c
 create mode 100644 src/hw_services/hal_core/gpio_services.h
 delete mode 100644 src/hw_services/hal_core/hw_abstraction.c
 delete mode 100644 src/hw_services/hal_core/hw_abstraction.h
 create mode 100644 src/hw_services/hal_core/timer_services.c
 create mode 100644 src/hw_services/hal_core/timer_services.h
 create mode 100644 src/hw_services/lwIP/lwIP_server.c
 create mode 100644 src/hw_services/lwIP/lwIP_server.h
```

Then I try to delete the lwIP branch, and it give me the next error:

```
fer@fer-Inspiron-5558:~/workspaceSDK/ControlMetro$ git branch -d lwIP
warning: not deleting branch 'lwIP' that is not yet merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/lwIP', even though it is merged to HEAD.
error: The branch 'lwIP' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D lwIP'.
```

And then it's impossible to push it... I'm really new at Git, and I was following the tutorial on Git page, but I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Paste output of console rather than an image. Use ctrl+shift+c to copy from terminal.

Comment: Done @Holloway , thanks!

Comment: There isn't a question here. What are you trying to achieve? Deleting the branch or pushing master?

Comment: I'm trying both, and no one works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not deleting branch 'lwIP' that is not yet merged to
>            'refs/remotes/origin/lwIP', even though it is merged to HEAD.

The output gives you the answer. The `lwIP` branch is merged into your local master but not into the `lwIP` branch on the `origin` remote. If you can't push `master` you may need to `pull` first to merge upstream changes.

You can either force the local delete using the `-D` option as it suggests or checkout `lwIP` and push to the `origin` remote. You may need to pull `origin/lwIP` into your local `lwIP` if you have upstream changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Now, I'm thinking that I've done a modification in the remote repository (a readme) and it doesn't exists in the local repository. So, I have to pull the master.